# How to have a alert pop-up after my click function (form JavaScripy&JQuery - homework projet)

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I cannot how to figure out to have a popup alert when all my conditions in my form are okay ... It is homework and the teacher want a popup alert after all the fields and if these are respected the last alert popup to tell "Our form doesn't have errors!". It is a JavaScript-jQuery form validation client-side only (no ajax or anything else). thanks for helping me!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    
// Les variables sont mise toutes à false par défaut 
      
          var validationForm = false;
          var validationPrenom = false;
          var validationNomdefamille= false;
          var validationCourriel = false;
          var validationMotdepasse1 = false;
          var validationMotdepasse2 = false;
          var validationInterets = false;
          var validationSports = false;
          var validatonDevweb = false;
          var validationAutres = false;
          var validationCase1 = false; 
          
//  Créer la fonction de validation au click du bouton 
    
    $("#submitbtn").click(function(){
      
       
                    
        
// Création des variables avec l'id des valeurs du formulaire
        const form =$ ("#form").val();
        const prenom =$("#prenom").val();
        const nomdefamille =$("#nomdefamille").val();
        const courriel =$("#courriel").val();
        const motdepasse1 =$("#motdepasse1").val();
        const motdepasse2 =$("#motdepasse2").val();
        const interets =$("#interets").val();
        const sports =$("#sports").val();
        const devweb=$("#devweb").val();
        const autres=$("#autres").val;
        const case1 =$("#case1").val();
        
// Validation du champs prénom 
        
    if (prenom == ""){
            alert("Votre prénom est requis.");
      
       
    }
    else if((prenom.length <3 || prenom.length > 30)){
          alert("Votre prénom doit contenir entre 3 et 30 caractères");
          
    }  
    else{
        
        validationPrenom = true;
    }
        
// Validation du champ nom de famille 
    if (nomdefamille == ""){
            alert("Votre nom de famille est requis.");
        
       
    }
    else if(nomdefamille.length <3 || nomdefamille.length >30){
          alert("Votre nom de famille doit contenir entre 3 et 30 caractères");
          
        }  
    else{
        
        validationNomdefamille = true;
    }       

//Validation du champ courriel 
    if (courriel == ""){
            alert("Votre courriel est requis.");
        
       
    }
        
    else if (courriel.indexOf("@") <0 && (courriel.indexOf(".")<0) ){
        alert("Votre courriel n'est pas valide.");
        
    }
    else{
        
        validationCourriel = true;
    }  

 //Validation du champ mot de passe 
        if (motdepasse1 == ""){
            alert("Votre mot de passe est requis.");
        
       
    }
        
    else if(motdepasse1.length <10){
          alert("Votre mot de passe doit contenir au moins 10 caractères");
          
    }  
    else{
        
        validationMotdepasse1 = true;
    }  

//Validation du champ mot de passe (validation)
        if (motdepasse2 == ""){
            alert("Vous devez confirmer votre mot de passe.");
        
       
    }
        
    else if(motdepasse1 !== motdepasse2 ){
          alert("Vos mots de passe ne sont pas identiques");
          
    }  
    else{
        
        validationMotdepasse2 = true;
    }  

//Validation du champ Intérêts
          if (interets == "Veuillez choisir"){
          alert("Veuillez sélectionner un champ d'intérêt.");
      
    }
        
    else{
        
        validationInterets = true;
    } 

});
    
    if(validationPrenom && validationNomdefamille && validationCourriel && validationMotdepasse1 && validationMotdepasse2 && validationInterets){
        alert("Votre formulaire ne contient aucune erreur!");
    }
    
 
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code scares me o.o

but to answer your question, you'r last `if ()` check with the final alert `alert("Votre formulaire ne contient aucune erreur!");` is outside your jQuery click function. So just move that up.

Answer (score 1):

Your last condition need to be in event click.
You can also use a array to check errors.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
// Créer un tableau pour la gestion des erreurs
    var formErrors = [];  
    
    // Créer la fonction de validation au click du bouton 
    $("#submitbtn").click(function(){
                
       // Création des variables avec l'id des valeurs du formulaire
        const form =$("#form").val();
        const prenom =$("#prenom").val();
        const nomdefamille =$("#nomdefamille").val();
        const courriel =$("#courriel").val();
        const motdepasse1 =$("#motdepasse1").val();
        const motdepasse2 =$("#motdepasse2").val();
        const interets =$("#interets").val();
        const sports =$("#sports").val();
        const devweb=$("#devweb").val();
        const autres=$("#autres").val;
        const case1 =$("#case1").val();

       // Validation du champs prénom 
        if (prenom == ""){
          formErrors.push("Votre prénom est requis.");
        } else if((prenom.length <3 || prenom.length > 30)){
          formErrors.push("Votre prénom doit contenir entre 3 et 30 caractères");  
        }

        // Validation du champ nom de famille 
        if (nomdefamille == ""){
          formErrors.push("Votre nom de famille est requis.");
        } else if(nomdefamille.length <3 || nomdefamille.length >30){
          formErrors.push("Votre nom de famille doit contenir entre 3 et 30 caractères");
        }      

        //Validation du champ courriel 
        if (courriel == ""){
          formErrors.push("Votre courriel est requis.");
        } else if (courriel.indexOf("@") <0 && (courriel.indexOf(".")<0) ){
          formErrors.push("Votre courriel n'est pas valide.");
        }

         //Validation du champ mot de passe 
          if (motdepasse1 == ""){
            formErrors.push("Votre mot de passe est requis.");
          } else if (motdepasse1.length <10) {
            formErrors.push("Votre mot de passe doit contenir au moins 10 caractères");
          }

          //Validation du champ mot de passe (validation)
          if (motdepasse2 == ""){
             formErrors.push("Vous devez confirmer votre mot de passe.");
          } else if(motdepasse1 !== motdepasse2 ) {
             formErrors.push("Vos mots de passe ne sont pas identiques");
          } 

          //Validation du champ Intérêts
          if (interets == "Veuillez choisir"){
            formErrors.push("Veuillez sélectionner un champ d'intérêt.");
          }
          
          // si aucune erreur dans le tableau
          if (formErrors.length === 0) {
              alert("Votre formulaire ne contient aucune erreur!");
          } else {
            // sinon on boucle sur les erreurs
            $(formErrors).each(function(index, value) {
              alert(value);
            });
          }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="form">
  <input type="text" id="prenom"/>
  <input type="text" id="nomdefamille"/>
  <input type="text" id="courriel"/>
  <input type="text" id="motdepasse1"/>
  <input type="text" id="motdepasse2"/>
  <input type="text" id="interets"/>
  <input type="text" id="sports"/>
  <input type="text" id="devweb"/>
  <input type="text" id="autres"/>
  <input type="text" id="case1"/>
  <input type="submit" id="submitbtn"/>
</div>
```